# Fast approximate algorithm for cardinality of sets intersection

Tags: algorithm, indexing, data-structures, hash, language-agnostic

I have a pool sets (with size of pool n), with all sets not fitting in the RAM. I can only fit only a small fraction, say 1-5% of all sets into RAM.

The problem is given query set Q I need to return top k sets with largest cardinality of intersect with Q.

1. Assuming Q in from the same pool of sets.
2. For general Q.

k is small, in hundreds, while n in hundreds of millions. Total number of district elements in all sets in hundreds of millions, too.

- There are many probabilistic data structures, KMV, MinHash and it's
  variants, which one should I use?
- Can I modify HyperLogLog for my
  task?
- Which of those structures can be assembled into some kind of index?

I did some experiments representing sets as bloom filters. Because sets size varies greatly I have to use very large bloomfilters, which is inefficient (bloomfiltes take 5x space of original dataset). Adaptive bloomfiters from https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter produce only 3-5x compression of the dataset, so this is still pretty much infeasible.

Comment: does "all sets not fitting in the RAM" mean that a) *none* of the sets fit into RAM, **or** b) the *combination of all* sets doesn't fit in RAM?

Comment: It means b). I can fit around 1% of all sets into ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I've found the solution. Intersection in given by multiplying hyperloglog and minhash, and minhashes could be efficinetly stored with LSH. More details here: http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/mmds/ch3.pdf

Comment: The linked document does not contain anything about hyperloglog.   Can you explain what you mean by multiplying HLL with minhash?  You mean just multiplying the estimated cardinalities of the two sets?  Can you link to a document that indicates that will do what you want?

Answer (score 4):

[K-Minimum Values](https://research.neustar.biz/2012/07/09/sketch-of-the-day-k-minimum-values/) data structure is extremely memory efficient. Unlike Bloom filters, it does not provide membership test, only set-theoretic operations and cardinality estimate.

Might work for you, depending on cardinalities of your sets and your error tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

Save all sets together in one bloom filter containing keys of the form `(setId, value)`.  This will have to be able to handle a set of the size of the union of all of your sets, which keeps you you from storing small sets in bloom filters sized for very large ones.

Secondly for your purpose you might accept very large error rates, which again lets the bloom filter shrink.  A bloom filter with a 1% error rate needs 9.58505837736744... bits per element.  A bloom filter with a 10% error rate needs 4.79252918868372 bits per element.  But if you have a 10% error rate, on a 400 element set you can, after correcting for expected false positives, have an answer that is 95% of the time within 3% of the right answer.  That may be acceptable to get the a factor of 2 reduction in filter size.  (The larger Q is, the smaller the relative error.)

If between these two techniques a bloom filter is still way too big, then perhaps you should look into distributing your data across multiple machines...

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the query set Q in memory as a hash table, there is no need to keep all other sets in memory at the same time. You can calculate the intersection cardinalities for each set one after another. Just load a set into memory, calculate the cardinality of its intersection with Q, and finally remove it again from memory.